# ColdFusion Rest API Call : URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

We are using a Rest API. On calling a login API if we pass `%` string then it generates this error from Application.cfc

> URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern

Is there any way I can get rid of this error? I got the below error that might help to replicate issue.

> URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern
>   javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
>
> Request - struct
>
> - **content**  : email=test@gmail.com&password=Test06489%&auth_type=0
> - **headers**
> - **Accept-Encoding**  :gzip
> - **IDFA**  :    c4ca9c604a15254b
> - **TOMCATCGIHTTPURL000000006A6B0000** : /rest/icon/api/v1/authorization/login
> - **X-ORIGINAL-URL**  : /rest/icon/api/v1/authorization/login
> - **X-REWRITE-URL**  :  /rest/icon/api/v1/authorization/login
> - **connection**  :    Keep-Alive
> - **content-length**  : 59
> - **content-type**  :   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> - **host**   :     example.com
> - **ndt**    :   H_GJvwvp8wXirIvs8AV-byQCiD7mfCmDclFH3lblksw75e-4U0CReX3-J
> - **user-agent**   : 2.0.2.5 rv:23 (phone; Android OS 6.0.1; en_US)
> - **method**    :  POST
> - **protocol**    :   HTTP/1.1

**StackTrace**

> javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.BaseFormProvider.readFrom(BaseFormProvider.java:86) at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider.readFrom(FormProvider.java:73) at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider.readFrom(FormProvider.java:58) at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:474) at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:538) at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.AdaptingContainerRequest.getEntity(AdaptingContainerRequest.java:225) at coldfusion.rest.provider.CFContainerRequest.getEntity(CFContainerRequest.java:85) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.FormDispatchProvider.processForm(FormDispatchProvider.java:103) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.FormDispatchProvider.access$000(FormDispatchProvider.java:68) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.FormDispatchProvider$FormParameterProvider.getInjectableValues(FormDispatchProvider.java:115) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ObjectOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:256) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) at coldfusion.rest.method.dispatch.RESTMethodExecutionFilter.invoke(RESTMethodExecutionFilter.java:42) at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:444) at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48) at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40) at coldfusion.rest.method.dispatch.CFExceptionHandlingDispatcher.dispatch(CFExceptionHandlingDispatcher.java:67) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339) at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416) at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537) at coldfusion.rest.servlet.CFRestServletContainer.service(CFRestServletContainer.java:143) at coldfusion.rest.servlet.CFRestServletContainer.service(CFRestServletContainer.java:88) at coldfusion.rest.servlet.CFRestServlet.invoke(CFRestServlet.java:384) at coldfusion.rest.servlet.RestFilter.invoke(RestFilter.java:58) at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94) at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28) at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at coldfusion.rest.servlet.RestWrapRequestFilter.invoke(RestWrapRequestFilter.java:46) at coldfusion.rest.servlet.CFRestServlet.invoke(CFRestServlet.java:356) at coldfusion.rest.servlet.CFRestServlet.service(CFRestServlet.java:347) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filterchain.WrappedFilterChain.doFilter(WrappedFilterChain.java:97) at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doNext(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:437) at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.handle(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:464) at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorCoreFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorCoreFilter.java:36) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filterchain.WrappedFilterChain.doFilter(WrappedFilterChain.java:79) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at com.intergral.fusionreactor.agent.filter.FusionReactorStaticFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorStaticFilter.java:53) at com.intergral.fusionreactor.agent.pointcuts.NewFilterChainPointCut$1.invoke(NewFilterChainPointCut.java:41) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:450) at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:197) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:187) at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.BaseFormProvider.readFrom(BaseFormProvider.java:80) ... 78 more

Comment: Please show some code and go through [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: where do u use %? give your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to url encode the % as `%25`. Like so, taking a hint from your error report:

`email=test@gmail.com&password=Test06489%25&auth_type=0`

Comment: Actually This is called from Api call from Android ?

Do we  have any option to avoid this from our side.

Comment: @Pritesh if you post the section of code that is finding the error in the request, we might be able to formulate a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding another `25` after my `%25` so the API call read `%2525`